# Определение живности лица на Camera2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, машинное-обучение

Уже несколько дней ищу Информацию о распознавании лица на Camera2 API.

Проблема в том, что из коробки [android.media.FaceDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector) распознает лица даже с картинок.
Мне нужно чтобы определяло только если `liveness`.

Нашел решение [Face SDK от regulaforensics](https://github.com/regulaforensics/FaceSDK-Android), думаю у них есть ограничение или платное.

Вопрос: Возможно ли распознать лицо без сторонних библиотек? Если нет, то какую посоветуете использовать?

Comment: Живность это сильно. Но никто не мешает сделать несколько "захватов" и определить, закрываются ли глаза

Comment: то есть, вы советуете так поступить в данном случае?

Comment: На вход Вы даете картинку. Оно возвращает положение глаз. Зная расстояние между глазами можно определить приблизительно размер глаз. Зная это, можно попробовать определить, открыты ли они или закрыты (желтые глаза бывают только при закрытых глазах или желтухе, поэтому по среднему цвету). А дальше просто следим за человеком и просим его моргнуть разок-другой. Если это фотка - то это сложно сделать. если живой - легко. Если видео - то моргнет не тогда, когда нужно. Также сразу спящего отсечь можно. Хотя можно на небольшие изображения глаз натравить махонькую нейроночку.